# Django form initialization issue - how to set localize in superclass?

Tags: django, django-forms, localization, initialization

I have a model form where I mix imperial and metrics units (e.g. m/s and fps) depending on locale of user, so the form is a mix of using form-fields added manually and referencing the model.

Now, we do this in many forms so have created a super-class LocalizedModel form that simply iterates over the sub-class fields and if decimal, then sets localized = True for all field.

The expected outcome is that when generating the form in template; all decimal fields should be localized (, or .) and use text-input and not number.

The strange thing is that;

- when using the super-class that iterates over fields and sets thing, form is not localized and number-input is still used.

BUT

- when setting localize = True directly in the field it works (text and decimal separator is set correctly)

Python 3 and Django 2.0.6 and USE_L10N is True.

Any idea why this is the case?

See code-snippets below

```
 # -- example -- 
class RecipeForm(LocalizedModelForm):

    cost = forms.DecimalField(label='Cost', initial=0, min_value=0, localize=True)
    cost_2 = forms.DecimalField(label='Other Costs', initial=0, min_value=0)

    # cost has manually set - works in template
    # cost_2 and weight - expected that LocalizedModel for should set them, but no

    class Meta:
        model = Recipe   
        fields = [
            'cost',
            'cost_2',
            'weight', 
        ]

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(RecipeForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

# ---------------------------------------------------------
class LocalizedModelForm(django.forms.ModelForm):

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        new_class = super(LocalizedModelForm, cls).__new__(cls)

        for field in list(new_class.base_fields.values()):
            if isinstance(field, django.forms.DecimalField):
                field.localize = True
                field.widget.is_localized = True

    return new_class
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are changing the field property, after it has already been initialized, which basically means that the field has already rendered `NumberInput` widget since it was initialized without `localize` attribute.

The solution is to either call the field's `__init__` method with the proper arguments to re-initialize the object.

Or, looking at class `IntegerField` (super class of `DecimalField`) [__init__](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.11/django/forms/fields.py#L265) method, you can see that if `localize` is `True` and `widget` is `NumberInput`, then it will always set the widget of the super class `Field` as `TextInput`.

**Solution**:

```
from django.forms.widgets import TextInput

def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
    new_class = super(LocalizedModelForm, cls).__new__(cls)

    # keep the same reference to the field, change to `items`.
    for field_name, field in new_class.base_fields.items():
        if isinstance(field, django.forms.DecimalField):
            widget = TextInput()
            extra_attrs = field.widget_attrs(widget)
            if extra_attrs:
                widget.attrs.update(extra_attrs)
            field.widget = widget

    return new_class
```

Comment: Thanks, had a feeling it had with ordering of initialization of things and this solved it for me :-)